# Bean in DispatcherServlet accessing sibling bean

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

We have a web application with both a root application context (`applicationContext.xml`) and a dispatcher servlet (`dispatcher-servlet.xml`) defined in our `web.xml` like so:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

...

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Due to the access restrictions, we obviously cannot access any of the `DispatcherServlet` beans from the root parent context.

But, *what we'd like to be able to do* is access the **sibling** beans. For example, in our `dispatcher-servlet.xml` we have:

```
<bean id="firstController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="secondController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController">
...
</bean>
```

**How can we access** the `secondController` from inside `firstController`, without requiring that it be passed in as a constructor-arg, or set as a property?

We're using `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(...)` to access siblings in the root `applicationContext.xml`, but we'd like to do the same thing in the child context. (From within one of the children.)

Comment: what is the spring version? can you use @Autowired ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get an `ApplicationContext` object using

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dispatcher-servlet.xml")`

This is assuming `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is in class path. context object has to be cached.
Then use `context.getBean()` to access beans from any where.

Other option seems to be , use overloaded method where we can pass the context attribute name. I have not used it. 
`WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc, String attrName)`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just using `@Autowired` and keeping it around as an ivar, but in the future I'll examine the extra-parametered `getWebApplicationContext()`.